# How to use FastAPI Depends objetcs with asyncio?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI endpoint where it need to download some files from HDFS to the local server.

I'm trying to use asyncio to run the function that will download the files in a separate process.

I'm using FastAPI Depends to create a HDFS client and inject the object in the endpoint execution.

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request, Response, status
from hdfs import InsecureClient
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor

app = FastAPI()

HDFS_URLS = ['http://hdfs-srv.local:50070']

async def run_in_process(fn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(app.state.executor, fn, *args)  # wait and return result

def connectHDFS():
    client = InsecureClient(url)
    yield client

def fr(id, img, client):
    # my code here

    client.download(id_identifica_foto_dir_hdfs,  id_identifica_foto_dir_local, True, n_threads=2)

    # my code here

    return jsonReturn


@app.post("/")
async def main(request: Request, hdfsclient: InsecureClient = Depends(connectHDFS)):

    # Decode the received message
    data = await request.json()
    message = base64.b64decode(data['data']).decode('utf-8').replace("'", '"')
    message = json.loads(message)

    res = await run_in_process(fr, message['id'], message['img'], hdfsclient)

    return {
        "message": res
    }

@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    app.state.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def on_shutdown():
    app.state.executor.shutdown()
```

But I'm not able to pass ahead the `hdfsclient` object:

```
res = await run_in_process(fr, message['id'], message['img'], hdfsclient)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 202, in app
    dependant=dependant, values=values, is_coroutine=is_coroutine
  File "/home/kleyson/.virtualenvs/reconhecimentofacial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 148, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "./asgi.py", line 86, in main
    res = await run_in_process(fr, message['id'], message['img'], hdfsclient)
  File "./asgi.py", line 22, in run_in_process
    return await loop.run_in_executor(app.state.executor, fn, *args)  # wait and return result
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 236, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

How can have the `hdfsclient` available inside the `def fr()` function without the need to create a new connection on every new request ? I mean, how to create the `hdfsclient` on the application startup and be able to use it inside the function ?

Answer (score 0):

***The entire point of `asyncio` is to do what you are trying to achieve in the same process.***

The typical example is a web crawler, where you open multiple requests, within the same thread/process, and then wait for them to finish. This way, you will get data from multiple `urls` without having to wait each single request before starting the next one.

The same applies in your case: call your `async` function that downloads the file, do your stuff and then wait for the file download to complete (if it hasn't completed yet). Sharing data between processes is not trivial, and your function is not working because of that reason.

I suggest you to first understand what `async` is and how it works, before jumping into doing something that you don't understand.

**Some tutorials on `asyncio`**

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/asyncio-introduction

https://realpython.com/lessons/what-asyncio/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I understand all those cases that you mentioned. I'm just looking for a possible solution for my case.

Comment: Point is, you're using a screwdriver instead of a hammer to hang a nail. Sharing variables between processes is non-trivial and is likely to lead to errors. You're free to use the tool you want, but any other answer will either be really complicate or suggest to use asyncio the way it was thought